# Behavior of R pipe operator after transformation

Tags: r, pipe

I am struggling to understand the behavior of the pipe operator (`|>` in base R, but I have the same problem with magrittr's `%>%`) when I apply a transformation in one of the steps:

```
table(iris$Species) |> prop.table() |> round(1)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
       0.3        0.3        0.3 



table(iris$Species) |> prop.table()*100 |> round(1)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
  33.33333   33.33333   33.33333
```

Why the second command does not pass the result to `round`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, it is only the `100` that is passed to `round()` -- so it doesn't affect anything since 100 is already a whole number. The same thing happens with `%>%`.

With `magrittr`'s pipe, we can fix this by calling `*` as a function explicitly with backticks:

```
table(iris$Species) %>% prop.table() %>% `*`(100) %>% round(1)
```

Within base R, AFAIK we have to include an anonymous function to multiply:

```
table(iris$Species) |> prop.table() |> (\(x) x * 100)() |> round(1)
```

(But see [Anoushiravan R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67849167/7010056) for a workaround.)

Comment: Such an interesting interpretation of anonymous function. Would you please explain it a little for me as I've never seen this form of syntax before? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This syntax was introduced in R 4.1 along with the native pipe. `\(x)` is a synonym for `function(x)`, I think it's supposed to look like a lambda :)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you is there any documentation where I can read about it?

Comment: [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/new-features-in-r-4-1-0/#shorthand-syntax-for-anonymous-functions) is a great introduction.

Answer (score 4):

This can only be a second alternative to the very good solutions provided by dear [@ktiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67849124/14314520) which also contains some interesting new features.
We can use `multiply_by` function from `magrittr` package, which works with native pipe as well as magrittr pipe:

```
library(magrittr)

table(iris$Species) |> prop.table() |> multiply_by(100) |> round(digits = 1)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
      33.3       33.3       33.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert to `data.frame` and use `transform`

```
table(iris$Species) |> 
     prop.table() |> 
     as.data.frame() |>
     transform(Freq = round(Freq * 100, 1))
```

-ouptut

```
        Var1 Freq
1     setosa 33.3
2 versicolor 33.3
3  virginica 33.3
```